# Looking for a Hashing function given static number of buckets

Tags: python-3.x

I've a a fixed number of buckets and N number of inputs. I'd like the first n values of N to go into same bucket e.g

If I've 6 buckets and 16 entries, I'd like the first 3 values (0,1,2) to go into bucket 1,

(3,4,5) bucket 2 etc. The entries are sorted ascending order.

Which hashing function could I possibly use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use integer division then?

```
for i, entry in enumerate(entries):
    bucket = i // 3
    # insert into choosen bucket number
```

For 0, 1 and 2, that'll result in bucket `0`, for 3, 4 and 5, it'll be `1`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, how I didn't see that!!